# UISearchDisplayController displaying unfiltered data

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Thank you for reading my question.  I have an interesting problem that I cannot figure out and hoping the community may be able to help.  I have a `UITableViewController` (LibraryViewController) that has a `UISearchDisplayController` as a variable.  I have two other objects.  First, a subclass of `NSObject` that defines my data object (two `NSString` objects), called LibraryDataObject.  The second, a subclass of `NSObject` that has two `NSMutableArray` objects and implements the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol called LibraryDataModel.

LibraryViewController also owns an instance of a LibraryDataModel called libraryDataSource.  It is initialized properly.  Also, the delegates for LibraryViewController and the `UISearchDisplayController` are set to LibraryDataModel.  The non-searched view populates correctly.  And, when I search, the list populates the correct items based on the search terms.  The code is based on the TableSearch documentation code.

Here is where my problem becomes evident.  When searching, the table is reduced to the terms in the search box.  However, when I scroll the table, and move beyond the bounds of the search terms, it starts messaging `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` with the tableview of the base `UITableViewController`.

Has anyone ran into this particular condition before?  Thank you.

Comment: Your title and question don't match up, did you mean unfiltered instead of unsorted?

Comment: Is your `LibraryDataSource` `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method returning the correct number of rows for the search results table?

Comment: @CarlVeazey I apologize.  Yes, unfiltered, not unsorted.  I'll see if I can update the title.

Comment: @alanduncan Yes it is getting called and returning the correct number.  `LibraryDataSource` `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` provides the correct number when unfiltered.  Once I click on the search box, each character reduces the count to the appropriate amount and displays the appropriate table items.  It is when I scroll beyond the bounds of the  filtered table that messages for the unfiltered table view are sent to `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Facing the same problem right now. Did you get around this?

Comment: @chris I have not found an answer.  I have debugged many instances.  Maybe we can work on it together.  I can forward you my code and I can review yours and maybe we can find a common culprit?

Comment: @chris and all.  I opened a case with Apple and they helped me out.  The behavior isn't what I want, but it explains this problem.  I was adding the search bar by pushing it onto the stack with [self.parentViewController.view addSubview:searchBar];  However, I should have added the search bar with self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;  This problem went away, however the search bar is at the top of the tableview, and not static on the view.  Seeing if that can be modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a case with Apple and they helped me out. The behavior isn't what I want, but it explains this problem. I was adding the search bar by pushing it onto the stack with [self.parentViewController.view addSubview:searchBar]; However, I should have added the search bar with self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar; This problem went away, however the search bar is at the top of the tableview, and not static on the view. Seeing if that can be modified.